# Rails SQL sort posts by recently favorited

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, sorting, join

I know this may be kinda simple, but I'm not so good with SQL and nothing I've seen so far it's it on the head:
I want to sort posts in my Rails controller by the time that they were "favorited" ie. the time that the "favorite" relationship was created"

Here is my controller with my attempt:

```
def recent_favorites

  recent_favorites = "SELECT posts.id 
                FROM posts
                JOIN favorites ON favorited_id = posts.id
                GROUP BY posts.id
                ORDER BY favorites.created_at DESC"

  @title = 'Recently Favorited'
  @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
  @posts = @user.favorite_posts.where("posts.id IN (#{recent_favorites})")
end
```

Here are my tables:

```
create_table "favorites", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "favorited_type"
t.integer  "favorited_id"
t.integer  "user_id"
t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
t.index ["favorited_type", "favorited_id"], name: "index_favorites_on_favorited_type_and_favorited_id"
t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_favorites_on_user_id"
end

create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "post_type"
t.text     "content"
t.string   "body_parts"
t.integer  "duration"
t.text     "equipment"
t.integer  "calories"
t.text     "ingredients"
t.integer  "user_id"
t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
t.string   "picture"
t.string   "title"
t.integer  "carbs"
t.integer  "fat"
t.integer  "protein"
t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_posts_on_user_id"
end
```

What am I missing to get this done?

thank you,

Comment: What is the problem with your current query?  I don't think you need `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the order-by to be on the final query, not the one that just pulls the ids out.

if I'm reading your sample code right, `recent_favourites` just pulls out a set of ids that is passed in to the `@user.favorite_posts` association... but it's *that* association that needs the order-by on it.

Perhaps try something like:

```
  @posts = @user.favorite_posts.where("posts.id IN (#{recent_favorites})").order("favorites.created_at DESC')
```

? (note there may be a bug... I leave it as an exercise to you to fix it if there is)